# What is the difference between createOrReplaceTempView(viewName) and cache() on a DataSet

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

Both of them are meant for fast access to the DataSet. What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`createOrReplaceTempView` registers a `DataFrame` as a table that you can query using SQL (bound to the lifecycle of the `SparkSession` that registers it - hence the `Temp` part of the name). Note, however, that this method does not allow you to achieve any performance improvement.

---

`cache` (or `persist`) marks the `DataFrame` to be cached after the following action, making it faster for access in the subsequent actions. `DataFrame`s, just like `RDD`s, represent the sequence of computations performed on the underlying (distributed) data structure (what is called its *lineage*). Whenever you perform a transformation (e.g.: applying a function to each record via `map`), you are returned an updated lineage. Whenever you actually perform an action on the `DataFrame`, some kind of computation for which the lineage must be executed, it will be re-executed every time, unless it's already been cached and it's thus available.

This means that using `cache` or `persist` will help you optimize such cases where you need to access the content of the `DataFrame` more than once.